# DNN upload files screen is always show when I load any page in administrative mode

Tags: admin, dotnetnuke

I am new in DNN and I have the following problem in DNN:
The upload page is always show when I change the page. This happen under the following conditions:

- I am in administrative mode (super user)
- Does not happen when I am login as normal user.
- Happen any time that I load a page in administrative mode.

I am using DNN 7.2.2 in Windows 7 over IIS

Please help me!

thanks

Jose Alfredo

[image: This popup is always show when I am in administrative mode and change to other page.]

Comment: Not a problem I have come across in the past. How did you install the software?

Comment: Thanks for your answer, I used a previous installed 7.2.1 version, and upgrade it to 7.2.2 using the procedure that DNN describe.work a time and then always comes the upload page, I can not determine what was the cause.